# Hilbert–Pólya conjecture with Grommer inequalities?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riemann-hypothesis

The Grommer inequalities are equivalent to RH and formulated on page 20 of [Conrey - Riemann's hypothesis](https://aimath.org/%7Ekaur/publications/90.pdf):

Let
$$\Xi(t) := \xi(1/2+it).$$

Then RH is equivalent to : All zeros of $\Xi(t)$ are real. The functional equation for $\zeta$ is equivalent to $\Xi(t) = \Xi(-t)$. Let $Y(t):= \Xi(\sqrt{t})$ and let

$$-\frac{Y'(t)}{Y(t)} = s_1+s_2t+s_3t^2+\dotsb$$

and set $k(a,b) := s_{a+b}$.
Let $K_N := ((k(m,n))_{1\le m,n\le N}$ and $D_N:=\det(K_N)$.

Then the Grommer inequalities are equivalent to RH:

$$\text{RH} \iff D_N > 0 \forall N \in \mathbb{N}.$$

But this is by the [Sylvester criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) equivalent to thematrices $K_N$ being positive definite ($K_N>0$) for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

**What is unclear to me:
Is $K_N > 0$ $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ equivalent to the function $k$ being positive definite over the natural numbers?**

If this is the case, one could have a candidate for the Hilbert–Pólya conjecture:
By the [Moore–Aronszajn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Feature_maps), there exists a mapping:

$$\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H$$

in some Hilbert space $H=l_2$, such that:

$$k(a,b)  = \left\langle \phi(a), \phi(b) \right\rangle \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Define on a dense subspace $D :=\{ x | x \text{ has only finitely many nonzero entries } x_i\} \subset l_2$ the operator $R$ via:

$$R(e_n) := \phi(n)$$

and for $x = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i e_i  \in D$:

$$R(x) := \sum_{i=1}^N x_i R(e_i), R: D \rightarrow D$$

where $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis in the Hilbert space $l_2$.

Set $O:= R^*R$. Then $O:D \rightarrow D$ is a positive, densely defined, self-adjoint operator, with the property:

$$\left\langle O(e_m),e_n \right\rangle = \left\langle R^*R (e_m) , e_n \right\rangle  = \left\langle R(e_m),R(e_n)\right\rangle = k(m,n).$$

Then by Grommer inequalities and Sylvester's criterion (/modulo my question above can be answered positively) :

$O$ is a positive operator with the property $O=R^*R$ for some $R$ and $\left\langle O(e_m),e_n \right\rangle = k(m,n).$ $\iff$ $k$ is a positive definite function on the natural numbers $\iff$ RH.

**Edit**:
There seems to be confusion about this question, so please let me clarify:
I am not saying that this question is proving RH. What I am saying is, that $O>0 \iff k > 0 \iff \text{Grommer's ineq.} \iff RH$ and so, this makes $O$ an candidate for the Hilbert-Polya conjecture in some wide sense.

Second question:
I tried to implement this idea in Sagemath to have some empirical backup, but without success since Sagemath cannot cope with the $\sqrt{t}$ in the series expansion, but it seems that Mathematica can, since I tried a little bit on Wolfram Alpha. **Is it possible for someone with Mathematica to try and implement this idea for empirical backup?** (I would define the matrix $K_N$ and see if it is positive definite for say $N=1,\dotsc,200$, and look at the eigenvalues of the matrix and compare them with OEIS sequence.)

Related question: [Spectrum of "infinite-Gram matrix"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739370/spectrum-of-infinite-gram-matrix)

Comment: I think that your operator $O$ is positive semi-definite, i.e., its quadratic form is non-negative. I see no reason why it should be (strictly) positive definite. It follows that its compressions are also positive semi-definite but there is no argument for their strict positivity.

Comment: @Twi: By the criterion of Sylvester on positive definite matrices?

Comment: No. I'm only saying that you know $O\geq0$. It follows that $O_{N}\geq0$ for all $N$. But you need $O_{N}>0$ for the Grommer ineq.

Comment: @Twi I do not understand your comment. If $O>0$ then $O_n>0$ and so by Sylvester's criterion $\det(O_N)>0$. On the other hand: If by Grommer ineq. $\det(O_n)>0$ then by Sylvester criterion $O_N>0$ and so $O>0$. It would be nice if you could elaborate on your comment, as I really do not see what you mean.

Comment: If you are able to show that $O>0$ (it is not proven in your post) then the first chain of implications in your argument would be OK. My comment is that you only have $O\geq0$, and not $O>0$. This is why your post does not prove RH.

Comment: @Twi: I did not say that it proves RH. I said that $O>0$ is equivalent to $RH$.

Comment: OK, so no misunderstanding in this. 
Another comment: I don't agree with the opposite implication RH $\Rightarrow$ $O>0$. From $O_{N}>0$ for all $N$, it does not follow that $O>0$ (only $O\geq0$) because $O$ can have $0$ in its spectrum.

Comment: @Twi: So this answers my first question,right? Do you know under what circumstances on $O_N$ it follows that also $O>0$?

Comment: Well, your first question is my definition of "$K$ being positive definite over the natural numbers" and since you did not specify what it exactly means for you, I can't say anything to this. Of course, you could impose some assumptions on $O$ to guarantee that $O_{N}>0$ $\Rightarrow$ $O>0$, for example $O\geq c>0$, but it won't be the case here. I expect that the lowest eigenvalue of $O_{N}$ tends to $0$. So it must be something very subtle which is not a surprise when related to RH.

Comment: @Twi: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer the first question on my own:

Since the matrices $K_n$ are assumed positive definite and since each matrix $K_n$ occurs as diagonal minor-submatrix of $K_{n+1}$, we can apply inductively inductive Cholesky decomposition to find an embedding $\phi(n)$ for each number $n$:

Equation 1):
$$\phi(n+1) = \left(\begin{array}{r}
{C_{n}^{-1} v_n} \\
\sqrt{K_{n+1,n+1}-{\left| {C_{n}^{-1} v_n} \right|}^{2} }
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 2):

$$v_n = \left(\begin{array}{r}
K_{1,n+1} \\
K_{2,n+1} \\
\cdots\\
K_{n,n+1}\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 3):
$$C_n = \left(\begin{array}{r}
\phi(1)^T \\
\phi(2)^T \\
\cdots\\
\phi(n)^T\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 4):
$$\phi(1) := \sqrt{K_{1,1}} e_1$$

Now we have found an embedding for each number $a$ in the Hilbert space of sequences $l_2$:
$$\phi(a) = \sum_{i=1}^a f_{a,i} e_i$$

for some real numbers $f_{a,i}$, such that we have:

$$K_{a,b} = \left < \phi(a), \phi(b) \right > $$

But the value of $K_{a,b}$ is just $k(a,b)$ , so this proves that the function $k$ is positive definite over the natural numbers.

On the other hand, if the function $k$ is assumed to be positive definite over the natural numbers, then we have the matrices:

$$(k(a,b))_{1 \le a,b \le n}$$

will be positive definite for each $n$.

But these are just the $K_n$ matrices. So this proves the equivalence stated in the first question.